# Count distinct doesn't work when using OrderBy & join

Tags: servicestack

I have the following query trying to get count of a query:

```cs
var testQuery = Db
    .From<Blog>()
    .LeftJoin<BlogToBlogCategory>()
    .Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false)
    .OrderBy(x => x.ConvertedPrice);

var testCount = Db.Scalar<int>(testQuery.Select<Blog>(x => Sql.CountDistinct(x.Id)));

var results = Db.LoadSelect(testQuery.SelectDistinct());
```

It gives error:

> 42803: column "blog.converted_price" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Issue seems to be the orderby statement.  If I remove it then the error goes away.  Why does this stop count distinct working?

I am having to clear orderby on all queries I do like this.  Is it supposed to work this way?

Also I just realised count is wrong. Results is 501 unique records and testCount is 538.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever in doubt with what an OrmLite query is generating, you can use the [BeforeExecFilter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#beforeexecfilter-and-afterexecfilter-filters) to inspect the DB command before its executed or to just output the query to the Console you can use:

```
OrmLiteUtils.PrintSql();
```

You shouldn't be using `OrderBy` with aggregate scalar functions like COUNT which is meaningless and will fail in your case because it needs to included the `GROUP BY` clause for joined table queries.

Your specifically querying for `COUNT(DISTINCT Id)` if you wanted the row count for the query you can instead use:

```
var testCount = Db.RowCount(testQuery);
```

If you wanted to use `COUNT(*)` instead, you can use:

```
var testCount = Db.Count(testQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks that filter was very helpful in figuring out what was going on.